# Gitlab runner in docker '$ yes | true' returns with exit 1

Tags: bash, shell, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Running this command inside a .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
task:
  script:
    - yes | true
    - yes | someOtherCommandWhichNeedsYOrN
```

Returns:

```
$ yes | true
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Any clues, ideas why this happens or how to debug this?

Setup:
Gitlab runner in a docker

Comment: Smells like `set -o pipefail` is set in this shell. Since `yes` fails with an EPIPE when it can't write, and `pipefail` tells the shell to treat any failure in a pipeline as fatal (rather than only using the last command's exit status), there you are.

Comment: I've seen some other CI systems try to set a bunch of "helpful" flags that cause shell scripts to be fragile by default; gitlab behaving likewise wouldn't be surprising.

Comment: BTW, this single-command failure wouldn't cause your larger script to fail unless (1) it were the last line, or (2) something equivalent to `set -e` were in use to treat any individual command with a nonzero exit status as fatal. That's a much more controversial practice than one might expect. See the exercises below the allegory in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), and the table listing incompatibilities between different implementations of `set -e` at https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If running with `set -o pipefail`, a failure at any stage in a shell pipeline will cause the entire pipeline to be considered failed. When `yes` tries to write to stdout but the program whose stdin that stdout is connected to is not reading, this will cause an `EPIPE` signal -- thus, an expected failure message, which the shell will usually ignore (in favor of treating only the last component of a pipeline as important for purposes of that pipeline's exit status).

- Turn this off for the remainder of your current script with `set +o pipefail`
- Explicitly ignore a single failure: `{ yes || :; } | true`

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet.

I would extract the script in to a file and run that file from the pipeline with some debug stuff in it and see if you can reproduce it.

Make sure you make it to to, and not past, the line in question.

I try the following to get some more info maybe?

```
( set -x  ; yes | true ; echo status: "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" )
```

See if you have some weird chars in the file or some weird modes set.

Make sure you are in the right shell, true can be built in so worth checking.

Good luck.

Comment: `set -e; set -o pipefail` would cause this precise behavior; no weird characters or external `true` implementation required.

Comment: Would it give return code 1? That is what threw me off and I suggested to check yes return values of the pipe. In my env here I get 141 with -e&pipefail.

Comment: Good point -- `-EPIPE` is indeed what we'd expect there. That said, there's a good number of layers between the OP and the command they're running (gitlab, docker, etc); it's not hugely surprising for one of them to fail to retain original exit status.